# How to make CKEditor update the text content without using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor for mailbox. After typing the content in the editor, I need to click on send button. After clicking the mail goes, but without the content that I have typed in it.

This is because the CKEditor is not updating the value of content until I select the typed text and perform some operation from the toolbar, like Bold, Italic etc.

I have added a javascript: onclick to the send button and trying to reload the editor or perform some operation from toolbar .

Neither I can use JQuery nor any plugin to solve this. What else can I try for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this function to the page and call it on the onclick of the button. It'll update the textarea's with the value of the ckeditor

```
function UpdateFields() {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply....                                             I have tried using the above method, it works first time when I click on the send button(when jscript is called first time).             When I come back and type & send a mail the above method doesn't work at all. I have tried debugging and the control doesnt go inside the loop at all.  Any help would be appreciated..